# Not zooming the DIV element while zooming the page

Tags: css, html

While zooming the Web Page the DIV element will not Zoom, but the component placed inside the DIV is zooming and go out side of the DIV. Here I created a test fiddle [test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ablealias/Qhvvb/). Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: it's zooming, but you want see a real difference, as your div is changed dynamically to adapt parent's widths `<body>` element. By adding a fixed `width:200px` for example, you could see the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Div is taking up 50% of available space, irrespective of whats inside. The rest of the space is being left as margin.
For example if you zoom out from 100% (zoom out, not in). You can see that the contents will keep on getting small, but the width of the div will increase.

If you care about zoom-out/zoom-in looks, then use pixels instead of percentage.

Try it out over here: http://jsfiddle.net/fam46/1/

Comment: @Delphian: You are welcome. But, please find out about when to use percentages and when to use pixels on some articles. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965571/which-is-better-to-use-percentage-or-pixels - check the accepted answer for some tips.