# Trying to fit a camera video over another

Tags: html, css, video

I am trying to set a video over another one by using the css property by making the video position relevant to another one.

As you see in the pic I am trying to position the small video in the right corner. However the position of the small screen changes whenever I change the browser screen. For example it changes when I see the website in a bigger screen.

Can you please help me.

```
 <div class="containerdiv">
    <video class="own large" id="myvideo"  autoplay="true" muted="true"></video>
    <video class="own small" autoplay="true" muted="true"></video>
    <video class="peer large"  autoplay="true"></video>
    <video class="peer small"  autoplay="true"></video>

  </div>
```

```
    .containerdiv{

        position: relative; right: 0; top: 0; left: 0
    }

    .own.large{

        position: relative; top: 0; right: 0%;
        width: 40%;
        height:50%;
    }

    .own.small{

        position: absolute; top: 80%; right: 50.3%;
        width: 15%;
        height:20%;
    }

    .peer.large{
        position: relative; top: 0; left: 0% ;
        width:40%;
        height:50%;
    }

    .peer.small{
        position: absolute; top: 77.5%; right: 16.5%;
        width:15%;
        height:20%;
    }

    #camOption{

    }
    #switchPeerCam{

    }

</style>
```

[image]

Comment: "relevant to another one" you mean relative?

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

[screen # 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bbgp.png)

as you see here the small video is fit within the wanted place.

Comment: please don't annotate your question with an answer, edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

```
.own.small{
    position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 15%;
    height:20%;
}
.peer.small{
    position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width:15%;
    height:20%;
}
```

If you give your small window position as percentage, it changes when the screen changed.

Comment: can you please illustrate more, I am still a beginner in programming.

Comment: if you say 500px it is definetly will be 500px, but if you say 30% it will be the 30% of your screen. same thing with your example. bottom: 0 right: 0 aligns your window right-down corner.                                                   more info is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7965639/6479329 @faisal

Comment: but I actually did that, I gave my small windows percentages.

Comment: .own.small{

        position: absolute; top: 80%; right: 50.3%;
        width: 15%;
        height:20%;
    }

    

    .peer.small{
        position: absolute; top: 77.5%; right: 16.5%;
        width:15%;
        height:20%;
    }
as you can see the positions here are in percentage.

Comment: I have to use a unit. bottom:0 right:0 will make the small screen to set in the right corner not even above the large screen.

I tried to use px and as you said that does not work.

I need to use numbers other than 0 with the right unit. 

Thank you so much for your comments.